# Angular Directive not working with templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do a test directive, but whenever I attempt to use 'templateUrl' instead of 'template', my page appears blank.

This works fine:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

 app.directive('formSubmit', function(){

  return{    
    restrict: 'E',  
    template: '<h1>TEST</h1>'
   };     
  });
```

But this has the page appear blank:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

 app.directive('formSubmit', function(){

  return{    
    restrict: 'E',  
    templateUrl: 'test-index.html'
   };     
  });
```

The contents of 'test-index.html' are exactly what I described in the 'template' in the first code block, and the file is placed in the same folder as the app.js where the directive is. I'm sure I'm overlooking something very simple but help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

EDIT:

I appear to be getting the following error in the Chrome:

"Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

I looked online and apparently I have to run a web server locally. Is there anyway to avoid doing so in order to keep testing the app locally?

Comment: Check the path of test-index.html

Comment: As I stated, the file is located in the folder as the angular module. I even tried copying it to the main index.html file folder but the exact same scenario occurs. Thank you though.

Comment: Step1 - open console and look for 404 errors. Step2 - fix test-indes.html location.

Comment: try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server . Easy to use server.

Comment: Thanks @lujcon, that was very simple to get it up and running!

Comment: I don't think you need the .html file extension on your templateUrl